# Custom menu gives 404 in magento on server

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created a custom menu in admin tab in magento admin. It was working perfectly on localhost, but when i deployed my code on the server, it is giving a 404 page not found error. What can be the issue there!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_CoffeeFreak>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Inchoo_CoffeeFreak>
    </modules> 

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <coffefreakblock1>
                <class>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_Block</class>
            </coffefreakblock1>  
            <coffefreakblock2>
                <class>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_Block_EditSpecial</class>
            </coffefreakblock2> 
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <coffefreakhelper1>
                <class>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_Helper</class>
            </coffefreakhelper1>
        </helpers>  
    </global>    






    <admin>
        <routers>
           <samplerouter1>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_AdminControllersHere</module>
                    <frontName>print</frontName>
                    <modules>
                        <sintax after="Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_AdminControllersHere">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </samplerouter1>           
         </routers>     
    </admin>





    <adminhtml>


        <menu>
             <mymenu1 translate="title" module="coffefreakhelper1">
                <title>PrintInfo</title>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                <children>
                <!-- Note the misleading "module" attribute. 
                    It actualy refers to one of the declared helpers -->

                    <myitem1 translate="title" module="coffefreakhelper1">
                        <title>Add/Change Config</title>
                        <action>samplerouter1/settings</action>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem1>    
                </children>
             </mymenu1>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>    

</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server may be running on Linux which is case sensitive so you need to check that you module file and folder should be according Magento standard like controller should be `IndexController` not `indexController` etc.

and your localhost running on window which is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is when you are logged in. Logout and login again. Then it should work.

Comment: Perhaps check the magento log perhaps there are some helpfull informations.

Comment: I have checked! there is nothing helpful!

Comment: Please check my comments to R.S's answer! If you can get some info about error!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that cache is turn off / cleared

1) Logout and log back in again

If you still getting a 404 error

2) Check your server error log, you maybe missing your module helper file

Comment: Did you see any error in your server error log? Is cache is turn off / clear?

Comment: Let me see your config.xml or adminhtml.xml, do you have a acl?

Comment: I have config.xml in mymodule/etc/

Comment: Here is the hirerchy, app/code/local/my/module/(Block,controllers,etc,Helper) and I have template file in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\mymodule\mytemplate.phtml. I have a config.xml in app/etc too!

Comment: I have added my config.xml code above that is in mymodule/etc. as you can see in it <action> that defines print/settings in url! It is not getting the controller!

Answer (score 1):

Login In/Out,clear cache, should be the solution.
But you can try below points (though it may find foolish).
**1)** Check your xml contents.(line by line with your localhost xml)
**2)** Spellings matter (hope `<sintax>` spelling is correct is your xml )
**3)** Remove unwanted space (like before `<global>` tag) and comments.
**4)** Opening & closing of tags.
**5)** Proper Indentation (this will help to find your flaw if it is there)
**6)** Atlast directly copy the same localhost xml file in your server.

I really wish this will help you to find the bug.